# How to understand the negative sign in poor man's scaling for Kondo model?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, greens-functions

For the poor man's scaling for Kondo model

$$H_{K}=\sum_{k, \sigma} \xi_{k} c_{k, \sigma}^{\dagger} c_{k, \sigma}+\sum_{k, k^{\prime}, \alpha, \beta} J c_{k, \alpha}^{\dagger} \sigma_{\alpha, \beta} c_{k^{\prime}, \beta} \cdot S_{f}$$

there exists a scattering process which is corresponding to electron-hole pairs:

[image]

The corresponding scattering matrix can be represented as:
$$\left\langle k^{\prime}, \beta ; \sigma^{\prime}\left|\Delta \mathrm{H}^{(1)}\right| k, \alpha ; \sigma\right\rangle=\sum_{k'' \lambda,\sigma''}^{\xi_{k''}\in[-D,-D+\delta D]}  \frac{\left\langle k^{\prime \prime}, \lambda ; \sigma^{\prime}|V| k, \alpha ; \sigma^{\prime \prime}\right\rangle\left\langle k^{\prime}, \beta ; \sigma^{\prime \prime}|V| k^{\prime \prime}, \lambda, \sigma\right\rangle}{E_{L}-(\xi_k+\xi_{k'}-\xi_{k''})}\\=\sum_{k^{\prime \prime}}^{\xi_{k''}\in[-D,-D+\delta D]} \frac{J^{2}\left(\sigma^{b} \sigma^{a}\right)_{\beta, \alpha} \cdot\left(S_{f}^{a} S_{f}^{b}\right)_{\sigma^{\prime} \sigma}}{E_{L}-\left(\xi_{k}+\xi_{k^{\prime}}-\xi_{k^{\prime \prime}}\right)}$$
However, **it seems that I miss a  minus sign**, compared with the correct result. I know that we need to introduce an additional sign $(2S+1)^F$ according to the Feynman rule and there exists one loop in the diagram, but I cannot understand the relation between such rule and the above deriviation.

### Correct Result:

This scattering term is corresponding to:
$$\left\langle k^{\prime}, \beta ; \sigma^{\prime}\left|\Delta \mathrm{H}^{(1)}\right| k, \alpha ; \sigma\right\rangle=-\sum_{k^{\prime \prime}}^{\xi_{k''}\in[-D,-D+\delta D]} \frac{J^{2}\left(\sigma^{b} \sigma^{a}\right)_{\beta, \alpha} \cdot\left(S_{f}^{a} S_{f}^{b}\right)_{\sigma^{\prime} \sigma}}{E_{L}-\left(\xi_{k}+\xi_{k^{\prime}}-\xi_{k^{\prime \prime}}\right)}\\ \approx -J^2 \rho \delta D\frac{1}{E_{L}-D}\left(\sigma^{b} \sigma^{a}\right)_{\beta, \alpha} \cdot\left(S_{f}^{a} S_{f}^{b}\right)_{\sigma^{\prime} \sigma}$$
where the $\rho$ is the density of states.

Comment: you do remember that the denominator is always negative, right? (because you are doing a 2nd-order perturbation theory where you project out the high-energy states) Usually in the poor man's scaling we approximate the denominator to be constant $-D$ with $D$ the (renormalized) bandwidth

Comment: @yu-v Thank you for your comments! Since the energy of intermediate states is $\xi_{k''}\sim -D$, I think the denominator of this term can be approximately to $E_L-D$, i.e. keeps negative like  the other 2nd order diagram (electron exciting). But it seems that I still miss a minus sign compared with the correct result.

Comment: Can you write the "correct" result you expect to get?

Comment: @yu-v Sure, I have updated my question.

Comment: Ok. It's not clear to me where you got this form of the correct result, and subsequently where is your mistake. I think there is a mistake in your formula because the order of $\sigma^a$ and $\sigma^b$ should be the same as of $S^a$ and $S^b$ (i.e. if $S^aS^b$ then $\sigma^a\sigma^b$) and when I take the correct order I get the desired result that this contribution is positive $\delta J \propto \rho J^2 \delta D / D$. But I'm not sure that this is the mistake you are referring to